# How do I measure the cost of a T-SQL query on the wire?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bandwidth

How can I calculate the size of a T-SQL query in bytes transfered across the network?

I know I can approximate it by examining data types of columns (varchars are an interesting twist though), but are there tools that'll give me the number of bytes (including and excluding TCP/IP headers) used up while transferring the query and its results to and from the SQL Server?

Comment: Perhaps use a network listener like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)? That should give you exact sizes for packets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using the Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio, you can toggle the "Include Client Statistics" from the "Query" menu.

You will get some network statistics like

- Bytes sent from client
- Bytes received from server
- TDS packets received from server

You can also leave that option on and get an average of all query executions.

Comment: Yeah, just get the free Management Tools http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/

Comment: Nice! I've been using it for a while, but never noticed that functionality. great!